# Under what circumstances exactly is the identity element of a certain function unique?

Tags: functions, semiring

I have a particular case in mind.  Suppose there is some function $h$ which eliminates elements of a set so $h(x)\subseteq x \forall x\in P(\mathbb{N})$

Now imagine the (possibly) abelian group formed by $h^n(X)$.

Now suppose we have two domains $X\subset P(X')$ and $Y\subset P(Y')$ where $X'$ and $Y'$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $X'\cup Y' = \mathbb{N}$ and $h(y)\in Y$ and $h(x)\in X$.

In the first domain $X$, $h^1(X)=X$ so $X$ is an identity of $h^1$ in this domain.

In the 2nd domain, $Y$, $h^n(Y)=Y$ so $Y$ is an identity of $h$ in this domain.

Is there any means by which I can show from this information that it is not possible that the 2nd domain coexists with $X$ in $\mathbb{N}$?  I'm also thinking that the proof of *if $h^n(Y)=Y$ then $n=1$* is trivial?

What are the circumstances required for there to be no string $h^n(Y)$ which is nullipotent over $Y$, i.e. $h^n(Y)=Y$?

Clearly $Y=\emptyset$ is one possibility. How can I prove it is the only one?
Does this construct above remind you of any known mathematical structure?

There is another perspective on this question.  If you examine this case above, you can see that the full set (either $X$ or $Y$) is also its own identity element for the operation $h$.

What are the implications of this fact, in general, if any?  I can see that it means there can be no $y$,$x \mid h(x)=y$ or $h(y)=x$ otherwise $h$ would have a non-unique identity within a certain domain.  Is there anything else we can deduce?

I am pretty sure this structure I am describing is a semiring.  $X$ and $Y$ are both absorbing elements of $h$ in their own domains and although $h(x)=X$ for some $x_n$, $h^-1(X)=X\neq x_n$.  Any insight will be greatly appreciated, particularly with respect to limitations on the coexistence of $Y$ with $X$ as mutually disjoint subsets of the integers.

Now suppose $h(x)=f(g(x))$ so $h$ can be decomposed into two functions.  Is it possible to prove that $f$, $g$, $f^{-1}$, and/or $g^{-1}$ must also be nullipotent over $X$ and $Y$ like $h$ is?

Comment: "Now imagine the (possibly) abelian group formed by $h^n(X).".... ummm... what? What is $n$ here? How does a set form a possibly abelian group?

Comment: What does "$h(X) \subset X \ \forall x \in \Bbb{N}$" mean? What is $X$? Is it an arbitrary set, or is it the domain of $h$? How is $h(X) \subset X$ related to $x$? It seems that this question is interesting, but nothing is clear. Please: clarify yourself, or the question will be closed.

Comment: @Crostul sorry that is confusing. Let me write it differently...

Comment: The condition on $h$ currently means that $h$ is just the identity (by applying the assumption to singletons). The whole thing with abelian groups is confusing me, as I don't see what set and operation is supposed to be this group.

Comment: @5xum How can a set form an abelian group?  I deliberately put (possibly) because I think a semiring may break some of the laws of an abelian group. But you might imagine a set x to be the set of all integers and if you start with the entire set as an element and h eliminates all factors of the least prime in the set then then h(x) might be that set minus the even numbers.  h^2 might be that set excluding the multiples of 3 and so on. I think there's a way closely related to the p-adics of defining the rarionals as an abelian group in this way.

Comment: Ohh, is the function $h$ supposed to be defined on the powerset of the naturals rather than on the naturals themselves?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yeah sorry, I changed that.  It was originally defined on something else but I simplified it for the question and wrote it out wrong.  Although they're not necessarily exhaustive over the powerset of the naturals.

Comment: I am still not sure what it is you want to form a group. Is it the set $\{h^n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ with composition?

Comment: (or maybe more like $\{h^n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$).

Comment: I was just thinking of $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I didn't even know this was possible for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You mean the first one? Then it will only be a group if $h$ has finite order.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft if it piques your interest at all, this is an abstraction of the Collatz conjecture. If you replace every odd integer with a set containing that integer and all the odd integers that lead to it, then the function described above is the inverse of the Collatz function. A proof that an identity in this algebraic structure cannot be decomposed into smaller steps, or a proof that no two structures can coexist in the integers would prove that the only cycle in the Collatz conjecture is the trivial one.